# Sending data to another bootable system partition WITHOUT USB drive

Tags: partitioning, usb-storage, transfer

I am currently in the process (and almost done) of getting my Hackintosh to triple-boot with Mac OS X, Windows 7, and Ubuntu.  I have the partitions installed, along with Mac OS X and Windows 7, but there is a problem.. I have a USB drive, but it is not formatted correctly to show up in Windows.  I have the Windows ethernet drivers on my mac (I tested them in another boot a long time ago) but need to move them to my Windows boot..  The hard drives for the Windows and Ubuntu boots are showing up on my desktop as hard disk, but they are locked and/or do not have writing priviledges... I have other things on the USB drive that I need, so how can I copy the driver from mac onto the Windows installation without the USB drive?

---

**Solutions I tried that did not work**:

- $ sudo cp ~/Desktop/driver.exe /Volumes/Untitled/Users/MS/Desktop/driver.exe
- $ sudo mv ~/Desktop/driver.exe /Volumes/Untitled/Users/MS/Desktop/driver.exe
- just manually trying to drag it into the folder.

Comment: Why can't you get the needed privilages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I used was just to install Ubuntu, and Ubuntu can write to NTFS partitions...
installing Ubunutu is pretty easy.. no paying or anything, just need a blank CD/DVD/some other acceptable blank media and bam.. just download the ISO from Ubuntu, burn that ISO onto a CD and install it onto a partition.. easy as that!

Answer (score 0):

### Mac OS X can't write to NTFS partitions

It is likely that the partition Windows is installed on is formatted as NTFS, and by default Mac OS X can only read (not write) NTFS partitions.

If you have Snow Leopard (10.6), you can use [NTFS Mounter](http://ntfsmounter.com/) to get write access to the Windows partition from Mac OS X.

### About that USB drive ...

If you are on Leopard (10.5) then my only suggestion is to copy everything off your USB drive onto the Mac partition and reformat the USB drive as FAT32. Then you can copy everything back on and be able to access it from Windows.

Comment: ok, that util would have been perfect, sounds like exactly wat I needed.. exceot it did nothing.. was that thing even real?  It asked for my password, and then did nothing... so yea...

Comment: It should have put a little cat in the menu bar, near the clock. See http://ntfsmounter.com/howto.html

Comment: hmm, I used the util and it just made an icon of a cat appear in my menubar for a split second and disappear... any other ideas?